# how filter same value

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables (**docs** & **doc_process**):

**docs**

```
id | content   | status
------------------------
1  | content 1 | 1
2  | content 2 | 2
```

**doc_process**

```
id | doc_id | user | status
---------------------------    
1  | 1      | 1    | 2
2  | 1      | 2    | 2
3  | 1      | 3    | 2
4  | 2      | 1    | 1
5  | 2      | 2    | 2
6  | 2      | 3    | 1
```

How can I select the status when all `doc_id = 1` have a value of `2`

```
doc_id | status
---------------    
1      | 2
```

`doc_id 2` not filter because `id = 4`, `id = 6` are not equal `2`

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to filter on two contidions? both doc_id and status?

Comment: no. filter if all status of doc_id 1 equal 2

Comment: What is your desired output? It seems like you want a boolean.

Comment: I wanted when all the status of the id 1 = 2 will show off

Comment: I am sorry. I do not understand.

Answer (score -1):

Use a conditional aggregation

```
select doc_id
from your_table
group by doc_id
having sum(status <> 2) = 0
```

Comment: I fear this answer is trying to answer a very very ambiguous question, and does nothing to explain how the question was interpreted. The OP asks for help selecting status when doc_id is something, but the answer here is opposite...